# Populate column with timestamp based on difference in timestamp value and minute value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a pandas dataframe with two columns as below, the second column has a date time value as the column name and the first column with values as 20,15,10,5,0 represent the minutes before the date time value of the second column name.

```
minutes     2022-01-02 21:00:00+01:00
20           5.53
15           4.7
10           9.15
5            26.2
0            26.54
```

I am trying to replace the minutes in first column with time stamps by subtracting it from name of second column where the output looks like below. I tried multiple things but with no luck. Could someone kindly help me with this?

```
minutes                       2022-01-02 21:00:00+01:00
2022-01-02 20:40:00+01:00     5.53
2022-01-02 20:45:00+01:00     4.7
2022-01-02 20:50:00+01:00     9.15
2022-01-02 20:55:00+01:00     26.2
2022-01-02 21:00:00+01:00     26.54
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conversion [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and perform the subtraction with [`rsub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html):

```
df['minutes'] = (pd.to_timedelta(df['minutes'], unit='min')
                   .rsub(pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1]))
                )
```

Output:

```
                    minutes  2022-01-02 21:00:00+01:00
0 2022-01-02 20:40:00+01:00                       5.53
1 2022-01-02 20:45:00+01:00                       4.70
2 2022-01-02 20:50:00+01:00                       9.15
3 2022-01-02 20:55:00+01:00                      26.20
4 2022-01-02 21:00:00+01:00                      26.54
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried with 'df['minutes'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['minutes'], unit='m')' earlier but was stuck at this point. The rsub function is quite interesting.

Comment: @ANewbie yes `r…` functions are quite useful, there are many more (`radd`, `rdiv`, `rmul`, `rmod`, `rpow`, `rfloordiv`, `rtruediv`)